# Android: How to display string on textview from console

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview

I'm trying to display string on the textview. I'm succesfully able to print it on the console from database, but I'm not able to figure out how to print all the strings on different different textviews. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText search;
Button insert;
TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5;
DatabaseHandler db;
List<History> history;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_word);
    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    txt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    txt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt5);

    insert.setOnClickListener(this);

    history = db.getAllHistory();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    db.addHistory(new History(search.getText().toString(), null));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Inserted: " + search.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    List<History> history = db.getAllHistory();
    for (History cn : history) {
        String log = "Search Strings: " + cn.getName();
        Log.d("Search Strings: ", log);
    }
}
}
```

This is my activity in which I'm bringing my all database value on onStart() function. Now here I have to set all the data coming from database on the textview. Here is my DabaseHandler class in which I'm taking out each row.

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "historyManager";

private static final String TABLE_HISTORY = "histories";

private static final String KEY_NAME = "history";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_HISTORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HISTORY + "("
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_HISTORY_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_HISTORY);

    onCreate(db);
}

void addHistory(History history) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, history.getName());

    db.insert(TABLE_HISTORY, null, values);
    db.close();
}

History getHistory(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_HISTORY, new String[] { KEY_NAME },
            "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    History history = new History(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    return history;
}

public List<History> getAllHistory() {
    List<History> historyList = new ArrayList<History>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            History contact = new History();
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            historyList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return historyList;
}

public int updateHistory(History history) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, history.getName());
    return db.update(TABLE_HISTORY, values, KEY_NAME + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(history.getName()) });
}

public void deleteHistory(History history) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_HISTORY, KEY_NAME + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(history.getName()) });
    db.close();
}

public int getHistoryCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    return cursor.getCount();
}
}
```

Please help in getting data printed on the textview. On the Log.d I can see all my data coming, one after another. But I'm not able to print all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's answer for "Thank You for that. Can you tell me how to set the data which I have printed in MainActivity on onStart() method (Log.d("")). If you can give me the code for that, that will be much easier for me."
try this:

```
List<String> listNames = new ArrayList<String>();//global variable

List<History> history = db.getAllHistory();
    for (History cn : history) {
         listNames.add(cn.getName());
    }
```

or, if have in History field date try is, after easy will sort:

```
Map<String, Date> historyMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();
    List<History> history = db.getAllHistory();
        for (History cn : history) {
             historyMap.put(cn.getName, cn.getDate);
        }
```

Comment: Thank You soo much for that. I don't have date in my database. How can I map this "System.out.println("Data from DataBase " + cn.getName());", on the listview, where the latest one come first. Sorry for bothering you but I need to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

You need make ListView in which will show your data from DB.Because you have many items datas getting from db. 
I suggest to the next version:

In xml file you creat:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_names"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...>
```

You need create Adapter for your list with next xml resource:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text_name"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

In java code:
in onCreate:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
OurAdapter adapter = new OurAdapter(..., List<String> yourListWithName);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

if you want a more detailed description of the code tell me.

Comment: Ya that will be good for me. Can you edit the code what I have provided and please help me in poulating the data on the textview.

Comment: Hey Imperator, I need to show the latest data in the database on top, in listview is it possible. That's why I was thinking of using textview for the same. Can you help regarding this also?

Comment: For showing last item history in top, you need easy sorted your list from items objects History class, that's all. Your code work, but you need delete textView items, and added initializing listView. I can give work adapter for your case and xml code for adapter.

Comment: Thank You for that. Can you tell me how to set the data which I have printed in MainActivity on onStart() method (Log.d("")). If you can give me the code for that, that will be much easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

For add last item in top you need next, create spec. internal class :

```
 class Holder implements Comparable<Holder> {
        String key;
        Double value;

        public int compareTo(Holder another) {           
              return another.value.compareTo(value);
        }
    }
```

and use him how:

```
List<this.Holder> listSortforLastInTop = new ArrayList<this.Holder>();
```

and

```
for(...){
   Holder holder = new Holder();
   holder.key=...;
   older.value=..;
   listSortforLastInTop.add(holder);
}
```